# Формат логирования

Tags: python, python-3.x, логирование

Настраиваю логгирование на конкретный файл так:

```
logging.basicConfig(format=u'%(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s] %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger('logger')
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('logger.log'))
logger.info('Hello from logger!')
```

Проблема в том, что в файле `logger.log` я вижу строку: `Hello from logger!`. Куда делись мои общие настройки формата вывода логов ? Почему нет времени и прочего ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Каждый handler имеет свой formatter.

Вы не сконфигурировали formatter для `FileHandler('logger.log')` поэтому он использует значение по умолчанию, которое не имеет никакого отношения к formatter, установленному для `root.handlers` внутри `basicConfig()`.

Для отладки, полезно поставить [`logging_tree` модуль](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/logging_tree), чтобы на дерево loggers посмотреть.

`basicConfig()` предназначен для простых скриптов, чтобы одним вызовом выполнить конфигурацию корневого logger. `format` параметр используется, чтобы сконфигурировать formatter у всех `root.handlers`.

В более сложных случаях, если вы хотите, чтобы дочерние loggers имели бы отличающуюся конфигурацию, то *вместо* `basicConfig()` следует использовать способы, которые могут сконфигурировать, не только `root` logger. Например, прочтите конфигурацию из файла:

```
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
```

[Формат похож на ini файлы](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging-config-fileformat).

Если хочется прямо в коде конфигурацию указать (или в yaml/json формате из файла прочитать), [можно словарь в  `logging.config.dictConfig()` передать](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#an-example-dictionary-based-configuration). Вот конфигурация для примера в вопросе (в YAML формате):

```
version: 1
formatters:
  fmt:
    format: "%(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s] %(message)s"
handlers:
  stream:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    formatter: fmt
  file:
    class: logging.FileHandler
    formatter: fmt
    filename: logger.log
loggers:
  "":
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [stream]
  logger:
    handlers: [file]
```

Самая гибкая опция это руками в коде loggers, handlers и formatters создавать ([`getLogger()`, `.setLevel()`, `logging.StreamHandler()`, , `logging.Formatter(format)`, `.setFormatter()`, `.addHandler()`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html)). Можно её использовать, если basicConfig, fileConfig, dictConfig не работают в вашем случае.

Answer (score 0):

А с этим кодом у вас возникают проблемы?

```
import sys
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='[%(asctime)s] %(filename)s[LINE:%(lineno)d] %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler('log', encoding='utf8'),
        logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout),
    ],
)
```