# Логирование python скрипта запущенного cron

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, python-3.x, cron

Есть готовый `python` скрипт, чтобы сильно не заморачиваться с запуском через `supervisor` я просто добавил в `cron` задание:

```
0 12 * * 1 python /pat/to/script.py > /path/to/my.log
```

Каждый понедельник в 12 часов запускается скрипт и работает какое-то продолжительное время, а в лог записывает информацию только после окончания работы, что не очень удобно, я не могу посмотреть инфо во время выполнения скрипта, подскажите, как правильно логировать процессы запущенные кроном?

Comment: так исправьте скрипт, чтобы выдавал нужную вам информацию в нужное вам время.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin много исправлять придется :) Тогда проще запустить супервизором, надеюсь найти более простой способ и получше познакомится с кроном

Comment: не ясно, при чём тут программы cron и supervisor. информацию вам выдаёт ваш скрипт. у него, что, недетерминированное поведение? один раз работает так, другой раз эдак, третий вообще никак?

Comment: В какой-то степени да, он работает по-разному в зависимости от данных, которые он собирает и там нет логирования в самом скрипте, если я запускаю его из терминала - получаю информацию в терминал, запускаю cron'ом и получаю лог только после окончания работы скрипта

Comment: что значит «нет логирования»? от какой программы тогда вы «получаете информацию в терминал»?

Comment: В процессе работы скрипта сделайте <code>tail -f /path/to/my.log </code>. Показывает? Возможно, в питоне есть отложенный вывод на консоль, как в perl ($|=1)?

Comment: Сделайте логирование в вашем `Python` скрипте. Для этого есть модуль `logging`

Comment: Сделайте логгирование, как правильно подсказывает @Alban, средствами самого Python. Там есть поддержка классического `syslog`.  Да и там можно наворотить гораздо больше и понятнее, чем в сложном shell.

Comment: @Smithson я смотрю `tail -f` в том то и дело, файл пуст и запись в него происходит после окончания работы скрипта, т.е. операции происходят последовательно, сначало отработает скрипт, потом запишет в файл, похоже действительно придется добавлять логирование в сам скрипт...

Comment: А если запускать с помощью `python -u`?

Comment: @AK Вас понял, переусердствовал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я рекомендую лог реализовать внутри скрипта.

Всё очень подробно расписанно в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html)

Для быстрого старта вот вам пример как быстро реализовать данный функционал. В начало файла поместите эти строки

```
import logging
level = logging.DEBUG
FORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(processName)s\%(name)-8s %(levelname)s: %(message)s'
logfile = '/path/to/my.log'
logging.basicConfig(format = FORMAT, level=level, filename = logfile )

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
debug = logger.debug
print = logger.info
```

Тут есть хак с функцией `print` для `python3`. Для `python2` этот хак реализуется иначе.

```
import sys
class LoggerWriter:
    def __init__(self, level):
        self.level = level

    def write(self, message):
        if message != '\n':
            self.level(message)

    def flush(self):
        self.level(sys.stderr)

sys.stdout = LoggerWriter(logger.info)
sys.stderr = LoggerWriter(logger.warning)
```

[via](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31688396/2101808)

Но вместо хаков лучше переписать принты на `logger.info`

Answer (score 2):

Вывод перенаправленный в файл является полностью буферизированным (то есть пока не заполнится буфер или явно его не очистить, то в файле вы ничего не увидите). Когда в консоли интерактивно запускается скрипт (стандартный ввод/вывод присоединены к терминалу), буферизация построчная включена.

В cron вы можете просто [`-u` параметр командной строки](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u) передать:

```sh
</dev/null python -u /path/to/script.py >> /path/to/my.log 2>&1
```

---

Сложнее не значит лучше. Вывод из простого `print` легче забрать чем к примеру редактировать logging настройки скрипта, упакованного в docker-контейнер, внутри него самого. Или даже просто, если вы интерактивно хотите скрипт запустить, то каждый раз лезть в него тоже не очень удобно. `logging` это уровень абстракции, который позволяет разделить: какие события регистрировать (с акцентом на относительной важности разных событий в коде, генерируемых иерархией loggers), от того кто эти события потребляет (handlers) и как они форматируются (formatters). Если logging используете, то удобно добавить возможность [читать конфигурацию, которая задаёт loggers, handlers, formatters из файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594688/23044).