# Как писать в stdout и в файл одновременно?

Tags: python

Есть python скрипт:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('my_log.log', 'w')
print 'test'
```

Он пишет весь стандартный вывод в файл. Вопрос: как мне и писать в файл, и одновременно выводить на консоль?

Comment: Используйте модуль `logging`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html

Comment: Unix традиция: `ваш-скрипт | tee my_log.log` Связанный вопрос: [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4675728/4279)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Как наколеночное решение, буквально выполняющее задачу, озвученную в вопросе: можно создать класс, который принимает два файловых объекта, и при записи в объект данного класса выполнять запись в оба файловых объекта.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys    


class DoubleWrite:
    def __init__(self, file1, file2):
        self.file1 = file1
        self.file2 = file2

    def write(self, s):
        self.file1.write(s)
        self.file2.write(s)

    def flush(self):
        self.file1.flush()
        self.file2.flush()


logfile = open('my_log.log', 'w')
sys.stdout = DoubleWrite(sys.stdout, logfile)

print("test")
```

В целом, для логирования рекомендуется использовать уже существующие решения, в частности модуль `logging`.

**Обновление.**

Для корректного перенаправления и последующего восстановления `sys.stdout` в Python 3 лучше использовать менеджер контекста [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout). В стандартной библиотеке Python 2 такого менеджера контекста, к сожалению, нет.

Пример использования (для Python 3):

```
import sys
from contextlib import redirect_stdout


class DoubleWrite:
    ...


with open('my_log.log', 'w') as logfile:
    with redirect_stdout(DoubleWrite(sys.stdout, logfile)):
        print('test')
```

После выхода из блока `with redirect_stdout(...)` значение `sys.stdout` восстановится.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64359/discussion-on-answer-by-insolor----stdout----).

Answer (score 5):

Используя модуль `logging`:

```
import sys

from logging import FileHandler
import logging


def get_logger(name=__file__, file='log.txt', encoding='utf-8'):
    log = logging.getLogger(name)
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # Будут строки вида: "[2017-08-23 09:54:55,356] main.py:34 DEBUG    foo"
    # formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] %(filename)s:%(lineno)d %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')

    # В файл
    fh = FileHandler(file, encoding=encoding)
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    log.addHandler(fh)

    # В stdout
    sh = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
    sh.setFormatter(formatter)
    log.addHandler(sh)

    return log


log = get_logger()
log.debug('foo')
log.debug('bar')
```

Можно настроить формат вывода, указав в Formatter `'[%(asctime)s] %(filename)s:%(lineno)d %(levelname)-8s %(message)s'` и получать такие строки:

```
[2017-08-23 09:54:55,356] main.py:34 DEBUG    foo
[2017-08-23 09:54:55,356] main.py:34 DEBUG    bar
```

Comment: Не стоит `import` внутрь функции помещать, если нет уважительных причин. Обычно разделяют код, который генерирует события (`debug('foo')`),  от кода, который определяет какого уровня события интересны (level), куда эти события пишутся (StreamHandler) и в каком формате (Formatter). То есть коду, источнику событий, может быть достаточно: `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`.  А level, handlers, formatters можно хоть [из файла читать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594688/23044) или в `main()` добавить `basicConfig(level=DEBUG, handlers=[FileHandler('my.log'), StreamHandler()])`

Comment: @jfs, рад что вы прокомментировали, т.к. эта тема импорта меня до этого постоянно волновала, и мое мнение такое: если внутрь помещать, функция становится самодостаточной и чтобы она заработала не нужно будет из начала файла копировать импорты (если же какая-то библиотека используется во множестве функций, тогда желательно импорт вынести в начало файла). Насчет указания уровня для Handler'ов согласен -- было лишним. А так, да, возможности настроить логирование масса, но мне нужна была самодостаточная функция создания логера, которую можно было просто скопировать из одного проекта в другой

Comment: Не стоит использовать copy-paste целых функций в качестве инструмента повторного использования кода. Создайте модуль, поместите туда желаемый код (с импортами наверху) и используйте этот модуль где нужно (помещать этот модуль в `_vendor` папочку или устанавливать через `pip` -- это уже по обстоятельствам).

Comment: @jfs, а почему нет? Если создавать модуль, тогда вместо копипасты функции будет копипаста модуля в разные проекты (через pip не вариант таскать свои костыли/обертки)

Comment: попробуйте отдельный вопрос задать, почему модуль является более предпочтительной единицей повторного использования в Питоне по сравнению с copy-paste целых функций

Comment: @jfs, а вы ответите на тот вопрос? :)

Comment: это не имеет значения.

Comment: @jfs, спасибо, исправил :)

Answer (score 3):

## Проксирует вызов на все содержимое списка

```
import sys


class CallList(list):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        def func(*args, **kwargs):
            for obj in self:
                getattr(obj, attr)(*args,**kwargs)
        return func


cl = CallList([open('file.test', 'w'), sys.stdout])
cl.write("0xDEFACE")
cl.flush()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def echo(file):
    with open(file, 'w') as log:
        while True:
            text = yield
            log.write(text + '\n')
            print(text)

e = echo('log.txt')
next(e)
e.send('123')
e.send('456')
```