# Python логирование в файл

Tags: python, файлы, логирование

Можно ли как-то записать в файл все, что выводится в консоль?
Знаю про существование модуля logging, но у меня слишком много print, чтобы переделывать все под logging

Comment: Напишите функцию в котрой два принта один в консоль по стандарту, а второй с параметром file в нужный вам файл, в чем проблема

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как писать в stdout и в файл одновременно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709220/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Осуществил с помощью

```
def printer(printing):
    log_file = open("log.txt", "a")
    print(str(datetime.now())+ ' ' + str(printing))
    log_file.write(str(datetime.now()) + ' ' + str(printing) + '\n')
    log_file.close()
    return printer
```

**И заменил все print на printer**

Comment: а можно было не заменять, а просто написать: `print = printer` и дальше пользоваться print :)

Comment: @gil9red: можно даже printer не писать: `from exterminate import AltPrint` `# $ pip install exterminate` (обратите внимание: текст отправляется в gizoogle).

Comment: @jfs, судя по [примерам](https://github.com/adtac/exterminate) какая-то дикая библиотека :) И судя по [коду](https://github.com/adtac/exterminate/blob/master/exterminate/AltPrint.py) текст отправляется в gizoogle только чтобы сделать перевод на язык Далеков

Comment: @gil9red если это не ясно, в моём комментарии не хватает смайлика ;)

Comment: @jfs, согласен, прикольная библиотека :)

Answer (score 3):

Мне больше по душе вариант с заменой `sys.stdout` на свою реализацию, которая будет делать всё что нужно. Вот допиленный вариант с [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/616686/5418360):

```
import sys


class Tee(object):
    def __init__(self, name, mode):
        self.file = open(name, mode)
        self.stdout = sys.stdout

    def __del__(self):
        self.close()

    def write(self, data):
        self.stdout.write(data)
        self.file.write(data)

    def flush(self):
        self.stdout.flush()
        self.file.flush()

    def close(self):
        if sys.stdout is self:
            sys.stdout = self.stdout
        self.file.close()


sys.stdout = Tee('log.txt', 'a')
```

И никаких замен `print` на `printer` не надо :)

Comment: хорошее решение

Comment: [Некоторые люди считают этот подход грязным знаком (но не признаются почему)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64359/discussion-on-answer-by-insolor----stdout----)

Comment: `s/знаком/хаком/`

Answer (score 3):

Как насчет пойти по пути наименьшего сопротивления и воспользоваться стандартными средствами в лице модуля [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)?

Если раздражает `DEBUG` в сообщении, нужно из `formatter` убрать строку `%(levelname)-8s`

А чтобы и дальше пользоваться `print`'ом, сделать простую замену (как правильно подметил в комментарии `andreymal`, при выводе с другими аргументами, а не только с самим сообщением, могут возникнуть проблемы):

```
import logging
import sys


def get_logger(name=__file__, file='log.txt', encoding='utf-8'):
    log = logging.getLogger(name)
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] %(filename)s:%(lineno)d %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')

    fh = logging.FileHandler(file, encoding=encoding)
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    log.addHandler(fh)

    sh = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
    sh.setFormatter(formatter)
    log.addHandler(sh)

    return log


log = get_logger()
print = log.debug

# Обходное решение надуманной проблемы несоответствия аргументов print и debug.
# Приятным "побочным" эффектом будет возможность просто писать print()
# print = lambda text="": log.debug(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    log.debug('foo')
    log.debug('bar')

    print('')
    print('foo')
    print('bar')
```

Консоль:

```
[2017-08-27 03:41:29,929] FOO_TEST_TEST.py:32 DEBUG    foo
[2017-08-27 03:41:29,929] FOO_TEST_TEST.py:33 DEBUG    bar
[2017-08-27 03:41:29,929] FOO_TEST_TEST.py:35 DEBUG    
[2017-08-27 03:41:29,929] FOO_TEST_TEST.py:36 DEBUG    foo
[2017-08-27 03:41:29,929] FOO_TEST_TEST.py:37 DEBUG    bar
```

Comment: У `print` и `log.debug` разные аргументы, можно случайно прострелить ногу

Comment: @andreymal, ну не нужно так пугать :) максимум что случится -- что-то не выведется или при попытке вывести будет ошибка, что закономерно -- не естественный ведь способ :)

Comment: А потом побегут сюда же с вопросом "аааааа почему принт сломался", забыв, что принт заменён где-то в начале файла :)

Comment: @andreymal по такой логике можно людям вообще рекомендовать не программировать, а то вдруг ошибутся. :)