# Помогите сохранить вывод python re в txt

Tags: python, файлы

Код:

```
import re
    
with open('d.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    text = file.read()

pre_spl = re.sub(r' ([\d])', r'~~\1', re.sub(r'[\r\n]', '', text, flags=re.S),
flags=re.S)
spl = [elem.strip(';') for elem in pre_spl.split('~~')]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for s in spl:
      date_val, _, lst = s.partition('>>>')
      print(*[f'{date_val}>>>{elem}' for elem in lst.split(';')], sep='\n')
```

Скрипт выводит результат в консоль.Помогите пожалуйста, как правильно (в какую строку) вписать в код:

```
with open("result.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
```

Чтобы результат(вывод) скрипта сохранялся в result.txt

Comment: То что вы передаете в принт сохраните в переменную и запишите ее в файл. И в print потом выведите туже переменную если нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Открываете файл прямо перед циклом, в котором вы выводите данные, в `print` добавляете параметр `file`, через который указываете файловый объект, в который нужно выводить текст вместо консоли:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("result.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as result_file:
        for s in spl:
            date_val, _, lst = s.partition('>>>')
            print(*[f'{date_val}>>>{elem}' for elem in lst.split(';')], sep='\n', file=result_file)
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать по нормальному, но я предложу интересный способ. Перенаправить стандартный вывод в файл:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('out.log', 'w')
```

Comment: @insolor А потому что зависит от цели. В некоторых случаях так удобно. Плюс никто не мешает кому-то другому написать другой ответ. Я лишь написал тот ответ, который хотел написать.

Comment: Ок, я добавлю тогда свой ответ. Рекомендую еще почитать дискуссию к этому ответу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/709226

Comment: @insolor Спасибо!