# error.log в aiohttp

Tags: python-3.x, логирование

Как настроить свой aiohttp-сервер, чтобы он складировал ошибки в файл /path/to/error.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать модуль [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) для ведения лога.

Пример на [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html).

Мой пример с комментариями

```
# ./logger_settings.py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('my_aiohttp_app')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# Объявление файла с логом.
# Путь - относительный от директории в которой запущен интерпретатор
fh = logging.FileHandler('app.log')
# Или полный путь
# fh = logging.FileHandler('/path/to/app.log')
# Устанавливаем детализацию лога
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# Ставим формат лога
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
# end of ./logger_settings.py


# ./__main__.py
from aiohttp import web
from logger_settings import logger
# ...
logger.info('Create application')
app = web.Application()
logger.info('Run server')
web.run_app(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)
# ...
```

Comment: вместо кода, можно в словаре, [yaml конфигурацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594688/23044) logging хранить (легче читать, редактировать)

Comment: А ещё можно читать и ENV, аргументов, или json. Хотя yaml - будет удобнее.